# How do you make the pop-up table of contents like the one in the CodeIgniter User Guide?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Visit that link and look for the table of contents button at the upper right of the page. I want to apply that to the webpage I am making.

What do you call that design technique? Any links for tutorial on how to do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create that menu you can use css and jquery. Create a div with

`position:absolute;top:-400px;width:auto;height:430px;`

and you animate it with jquery. At click, set top:0px. You can use also animate jquery function. 
LE:

`$(document).ready(function(){
                $('div a').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().css('top','0px');
                    $(this).addClass('opened');

                    $(this).click(function() {
                        if($(this).hasClass('opened')){
                            $(this).parent().css('top','-280px');
                        }
                    })
                });
            });`

`<div style="width:100%;background-color:red;position:absolute;height:300px;top:-280px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="width:80px;height:20px;background-color:black;bottom:0;position:absolute;"></a></div>`

It's a sample code. From here you can edit it and you can animate it. Good luck!

Comment: If isn't rush .. i can write a sample code for you, but only over 5-6 hours.. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Done. Pls check it. (with html/body and all tags of a html page)

Comment: wait I've found a workaround, you can simplify the jquery code by: $(function(){ 
  $('div a').click(function(){  
   if($(this).hasClass('opened')){ 
    $(this).parent().css('top','-280px');
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
   }
   else {
    $(this).parent().css('top','0px');
    $(this).addClass('opened');
   }
  }); 
 });